# Minimize custom CSS on WordPress same code different pages

Tags: css, wordpress

The problem I want to minimize the CSS that I am applying to different pages the code it's the same it only changes the page ID

Thanks in advance

Two different pieces of code as example:

1-

```css
.page-id-46560 .fw-page-builder-content {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

.page-id-46560 .entry-cover {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px) {
  .page-id-46560 .fw-page-builder-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

.page-id-46619 .fw-page-builder-content {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

.page-id-46619 .entry-cover {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px) {
  .page-id-46619 .fw-page-builder-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

.page-id-47450 .fw-page-builder-content {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

.page-id-47450 .entry-cover {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px) {
  .page-id-47450 .fw-page-builder-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

and

2-

```css
.page-id-30363 .fw-page-builder-content {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px) {
  .page-id-30363 .fw-page-builder-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

.page-id-30368 .entry-cover {
  display: none;
}

html>.page-id-30368>div:nth-child(3)>#colophon>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>#text-2>div:nth-child(1)>p:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-30368 .fw-page-builder-content {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px) {
  .page-id-30368 .fw-page-builder-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

.page-id-30373 .entry-cover {
  display: none;
}

html>.page-id-30373>div:nth-child(3)>#colophon>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>#text-2>div:nth-child(1)>p:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}

.page-id-30373 .fw-page-builder-content {
  margin-top: -90px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:360px) and (max-width:640px) {
  .page-id-30373 .fw-page-builder-content {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}

.page-id-30387 .entry-cover {
  display: none;
}

html>.page-id-30387>div:nth-child(3)>#colophon>div:nth-child(1)>div:nth-child(1)>#text-2>div:nth-child(1)>p:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have to base on the page IDs? If you need specific styles for specific pages, maybe those pages are based on the same template or can be?

If yes, you could write just:

```
.page-id-page-template-... .fw-page-builder-content {
   margin-top: -90px;
}
...
```

Comment: thanks for that i just created two templates and added the code for each template and works like charm.